# Is this reviewed question off-topic?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

Today i am reviewing close votes. Where i show one [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2684200/is-there-a-way-of-pasting-code-snippets-blocks-in-gmail-wave-gdocs) which have 10 up votes and one close vote. In the question OP is looking for plugins.

Question is:

```
Are there any gmail/google wave/gdocs plugins for code sharing?
```

Is that question is off-topic as  `recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource` or that question is on-topic?

Currently i skip that post as i don't understand properly. But, in future i have to close vote this type of question as a off-topic?

Comment: Pretty sure that's off topic; they're asking to recommend a google plugin.  I voted to close.

Comment: Yes, off-topic. It is an "old" question from when the site was more "starting up" and the ranger for questions permitted was broader. Very good to close it.and  @Daedalus (and others) has voted for that due to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Completely off topic.  Either you answer with a link, or in other words

> recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other **off-site resource**

or you answer yes/no, which is pretty much useless.  Who says you're right?  What about a week from now?

It's the job of search engines to index the content of the internet and to tell you if something exists on it.  It is not the job of StackOverflow or its members to be a search engine.